# Creating user id (0001, 0002, etc) CORBA/Java

Tags: java, unique, uuid, corba

I have created an app in CORBA which allows users to register and stores the information only while it is running. I have to assign a unique ID to each user who registers. The unique ID has to be in the format 0001 for the first user, 0002 for the second user, etc. Having looked online I cannot find much on figuring out how to assign these numbers in this format.

Unique ID is assigned to each customer. 
The unique ID is based on a counter which is maintained by the server. 
The first registration will be assigned the ID 0001, but represented as a string.

My servant code is as follows:

public class AccountServant implements AccountManagerOperations{

```
double topupBalance = 0;
int credit = 0;
int uid = 0;

public void topup(double amount){
        topupBalance = topupBalance+amount;
        credit = credit +1;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return topupBalance;
    }

    public int getUniqueID(){
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000");
        uid = uid +1;
        return uid;
}

public static Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

public static ORB orb;

public AccountServant (org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb){

    this.orb=orb;
}

public void storeAccountDetails (AnyTopUpAccount.KamaradAccountDetails myKamaradAccountDetails){
    hashtable.put(myKamaradAccountDetails.name, myKamaradAccountDetails);

}

public Any getAccountDetails (String name, AnyHolder myKamaradAccountDetails){

Any anyDD = orb.create_any();

KamaradAccountDetails tempKamaradAccDetails = (KamaradAccountDetails)hashtable.get(name);
KamaradAccountDetailsHelper.insert(anyDD, tempKamaradAccDetails);
myKamaradAccountDetails.value = anyDD;

return anyDD ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a 32-bit integral type that doesn't allow leading zeros. You could use the integer type for the unique ID and then format to display the id

```
private static final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000");
...

public String getUniqueIDText(){
    return decimalFormat.format(uid);
}
```